# how to lighttpd redirect with querystring

Tags: url-rewriting, query-string, lighttpd, friendly-url

Following url is working fine:

```
http://www.domain.com/address
```

but when I pass any querystring like:

```
http://www.domain.com/address?back=order-opc.php?step=1
```

It shows 404 page

my rewrite:

```
"^/address" => "/address.php",
```

i have tried so many different rewrite nothing seems to work...
how should i rewrite ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take in count the rest of the query string in your rule.

```
"^/address(\?.*)?" => "/address.php$1",
```

Comment: i tried this earlier but it was not working probably because of order of rewrite rules in my conf file, i moved this link to top and its working now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query string should be:

```
http://www.domain.com/address/?back=order-opc.php?step=1
```

Note the slash `/` as `/address` means `/address/index.php` or `/address/index.html` ( or whatever is your default document )